# TIZEN for SamsungTV app - Common is not defined

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app

I'm getting this "Warning" in mi js file, and because of this my code is not working (downloaded for the sample here: http://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/legacy-platform-library/tut00055/index )

It seems that the Widget.js file cannot be found (and then the Widget class cannot be instantiated)

this is mi Main.js file:

```
var widgetAPI = new Common.API.Widget();
var    tvKey = new Common.API.TVKeyValue();
var    Main = {};

Main.onLoad = function() {
    console.log("antes del alert");
    alert("Main.onLoad()");
    console.log("despues del alert");
    this.enableKeys();
    widgetAPI.sendReadyEvent();
};
```

and this mi index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
    <!-- Common widget API -->
    <script type='text/javascript' language='javascript' src='Common/API/Widget.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' language='javascript' src='Common/API/TVKeyValue.js'></script>

        <!-- Widget code -->
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="Javascript/Main.js"></script>        

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/Main.css" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body onload="Main.onLoad();" onunload="Main.onUnload();">
    </body>
</html>
```

As the tutorial Says, I also tried with this url: *$MANAGER_WIDGET/Common/API/Widget.js* but the Warning still showing and the class is not being instantiated.

Answer (score 2):

Simulator doesn't have webapis.js and doesn't support APIs in webapis.js If you use emulator or actual device. there may be no problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using TIZEN then you are on SSSP4. Common/API is outdated on SSSP4, hence this tutorial refers to "legacy platform".

As I mentioned elsewhere, the display-API include for TIZEN displays is

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='$WEBAPIS/webapis/webapis.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='$B2BAPIS/b2bapis/b2bapis.js'></script>
```